# Kendo-dropdownlist for VUE from array of objects shows "NO DATA FOUND" message

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-vue

I'm having trouble getting the kendo-dropdownlist for VUE working inside a custom component. The component renders, there's no errors in the console, but no options are shown in the list.

I've broken the code down into this bit:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <kendo-dropdownlist
      :data-items="months"
      :text-field="'text'"
      :data-item-key="'value'"
    ></kendo-dropdownlist>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "demo",
  data() {
    return {
      months: [
        {
          text: "January",
          value: 1,
          numDays: 31
        },
        {
          text: "February",
          value: 2,
          numDays: 28
        },
        {
          text: "March",
          value: 3,
          numDays: 31
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are writting wrong props, see [docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/dropdowns-wrapper/dropdownlist/):

```
<kendo-dropdownlist 
    :data-source="months"
    :data-text-field="'text'"
    :data-value-field="'value'">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Comment: Huh, Your selection worked for me. Thank you!.    For the record I did search the docs and I was following the example found here:  https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/binding/ which seems to be incorrect.